# When a keyword is searched in a text box,I get the previous results as output

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax

Home page form

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    Search your keyword
    <asp:TextBox ID="search" onkeydown="javascript:doAJAX(this.value)"  runat="server">
    </asp:TextBox>
</form>
```

This is the code for text box searching keyword.  When a key is pressed, my code is sending the previous key entered.  How do I get the current key?  The `doAJAX` function inturn calls another aspx page and populates this page.

```
Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Try
        'Response.ContentType = "application/xhtml+xml"
        'Build CategoriesList
        Dim strSQL As String
        Dim Mytable As DataTable
        strSQL = "exec GetAJAXSearchResults '"
        strSQL &= Request("keyword")
        strSQL &= "', " & AppSettings("SiteId")
        Mytable = myLib.GetData(strSQL)



        For Each row As DataRow In Mytable.Rows
            'strChartList &= row.Item("title") & "<br/>"
            strChartList &= row.Item("PID") & "  " & row.Item("title") & "<br/>"
        Next row

        strChartList &= "</p>"
```

This is the aspx code which has the procedure details...I tried to put an if statement before for..but wasn't working..

Comment: Show your code. It is not seen now

Answer (score 3):

Change `onkeydown` to `onkeyup` so it will be fired after content is changed

See this [link](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html). Events order: keydown (symbol is not inserted yet), keypress (the moment when symbol is inserted), keyup - after symbol inserted

```
'Response.ContentType = "application/xhtml+xml"
    'Build CategoriesList
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim Mytable As DataTable
    strSQL = "exec GetAJAXSearchResults '"
    strSQL &= Request("keyword")
    strSQL &= "', " & AppSettings("SiteId")
    strChartList &= "<p>" // see no opening tag in your code.
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request("keyword")) And Request("keyword").Length() > 1 Then
      Mytable = myLib.GetData(strSQL)



       For Each row As DataRow In Mytable.Rows
          'strChartList &= row.Item("title") & "<br/>"
          strChartList &= row.Item("PID") & "  " & row.Item("title") & "<br/>"
      Next row
    End If
    strChartList &= "</p>"
```

Should be something like above. I'm sorry, if statement is not from VB, I just do not remember details of how it should look like in VB. Hope you can translate C# if to VB if

Comment: but when i clear the keywords in the text box,i get all the results present in the database...I want it to be a blank page without any results..How can i do it?

Comment: @AnushreeSarathy Just test it on your server side - if received value = "" than do not execute database request and show empty results. There is no any magic.

Comment: For Each row As DataRow In Mytable.Rows
                'strChartList &= row.Item("title") & "<br/>"
                strChartList &= row.Item("PID") & "  " & row.Item("title") & "<br/>"
            Next row

Comment: This is the code 
            
             
            For Each row As DataRow In Mytable.Rows
                'strChartList &= row.Item("title") & "<br/>"
                strChartList &= row.Item("PID") & "  " & row.Item("title") & "<br/>"
            Next row
            
            strChartList &= "</p>"

Comment: I'm sorry, but I see no reason why I should try to understand that bunch of unreadable symbols.

Comment: should i include 'if statement

Comment: i want my search box to search the result only when 2 letters are enetered..Ho can i do it..Should i get a length of it and then perform the search..can u gimme the sample code

Comment: @AnushreeSarathy - see update code. But that is the last question here I can answer. You are asking questions you already must know or if you are completely new to programming should learn first. Or can google in 2 minutes, if you do have no time to read some book about VB.net